# how to convert mat to imageSource on UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, emgucv

I'm trying to convert mat image to something that I could set as ImageSource on UWP but I could not find any solution.
The only solution I found show me very bad image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB8oT.png

Here's my code:

```
           VideoCapture _capture = new VideoCapture(0);
      
           while (true)
           {
               using (Mat mat = new Mat())
               {
                   bool ok = _capture.Read(mat);

                   if (ok)
                   {
                       await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
                       async () =>
                       {

                           byte[] imageArray = mat.GetRawData();

                           WriteableBitmap writableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(mat.Width, mat.Height);

                           using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageArray))
                           {
                               using (Stream stream = writableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
                               {
                                   await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
                               }
                           }

                           imageCamera.Source = writableBitmap;
                       });

                   }
             }
```

Comment: Any updates for this thread, does the following answer work ?

Answer (score 0):

> how to convert mat to imageSource on UWP

Currently, the Image control only supports images that use [**BGRA8**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/imaging#create-a-softwarebitmap-from-a-writeablebitmap) encoding and pre-multiplied or no alpha channel. Before attempting to display an image, test to make sure it has the correct format, and if not, use the SoftwareBitmap static Convert method to convert the image to the supported format.

```
SoftwareBitmap outputBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer(
    writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer,
    BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
    writeableBitmap.PixelWidth,
    writeableBitmap.PixelHeight
);

var source = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
await source.SetBitmapAsync(outputBitmap);
```